# Remove downvoted question from my homepage

Tags: feature-request, questions

If I downvote a question, I don't want to see it anymore, it shouldn't keep appearing everytime someone answers it...

Is it possible to do that or at least add some form of ignoring a question?

(Ignoring tags is not ideal, because I want to ignore **specific** questions, not every single one with one tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this happened it would greatly reduce the urge for people to fix their posts, since the people they are trying to convince to remove their down votes aren't going to see their posts anymore.

Comment: You are not forced to downvote a question... I would ignore without downvoting, as there are a lot of questions sanctioned by the community (with 100s of upvotes) that I just don't want to see anymore

Comment: I don't have a problem with ignoring questions as a separate feature. I definitely would not like to see it tied to a downvote. If I misconstrued what you were asking for, I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

Would you want to then see it if it was edited (which might make the question useful and clear)? I can see your point though (but it would encourage people to ask the same question over and over).

I would like to be able to hide questions that are closed unless I follow a direct link (like a comment notification).

Comment: The type of questions I had in mind, I wouldn't want to see them even if the got edited... like the jon skeet facts one on SO (for example)